# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.*** is not a function (React-Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on an existing project and this function already works in the other components except in this component 'ComingSoon' which I have just created.
And I get this error in my code with trying to run it.

`Uncaught TypeError: this.props.activateAction is not a function`

My Component.tsx

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import { connect } from 'react-redux';
> import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
> import { IRootState } from 'app/shared/reducers';
> import { activateAction } from 'app/modules/account/activate/activate.reducer';
>
> export interface IComingProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ key: any }> {}
>
> export class ComingSoon extends React.Component<IComingProps, {}> {
>   
>   componentDidMount() {
>     const { key } = this.props.match.params;
>     this.props.activateAction(key);
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     return (
>       ...
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> const mapStateToProps = ({ authentication }: IRootState) => ({
>   account: authentication.account,
>   isAuthenticated: authentication.isAuthenticated
> });
>
> const mapDispatchToProps = { activateAction };
>
> type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
> type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ComingSoon);
> ```

activate.reducer.ts :

> ```
> import axios from 'axios';  
> import { REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE } from 'app/shared/reducers/action-type.util';
> export const ACTION_TYPES = {
>   ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT: 'activate/ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT',
>   RESET: 'activate/RESET'
> };
>
> const initialState = {
>   activationSuccess: false,
>   activationFailure: false
> };
>
> export type ActivateState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;
>
> // Reducer
> export default (state: ActivateState = initialState, action): ActivateState => {
>   switch (action.type) {
>     case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT):
>       return {
>         ...state
>       };
>     case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT):
>       return {
>         ...state,
>         activationFailure: true
>       };
>     case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT):
>       return {
>         ...state,
>         activationSuccess: true
>       };
>     case ACTION_TYPES.RESET:
>       return {
>         ...initialState
>       };
>     default:
>       return state;
>   }
> };
>
> // Actions
> export const activateAction = key => ({
>   type: ACTION_TYPES.ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT,
>   payload: axios.get('api/activate?key=' + key)
> });
>
> export const reset = () => ({
>   type: ACTION_TYPES.RESET
> });
> ```

I forgot a declaration or an import?
Is the approach taken correct?
will i need to configure something in the store?

Comment: I checked your code and all things are right, did you correctly setup your redux?

Comment: redux works perfectly with all the other old components except with this new component that I just created. What do you mean by setup your redux?
Normally Store remains unchangeable and actions and reducers too.
I just wanted to call a method which already exists 'activateAction(key)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution by referring to this subject [React Redux TypeError: this.props is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404983/react-redux-typeerror-this-props-is-not-a-function).

I just removed braces from component import in routes component.

> import ComingSoon  from './shared/layout/coming-soon/comingSoon';

instead of

> import {ComingSoon}  from './shared/layout/coming-soon/comingSoon';

Comment: so this is not a problem with your current file, you described am I right?

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your solution, you need to `dispatch` your action before connect it

```
export const activateAction = key => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPES.ACTIVATE_ACCOUNT,
        payload: axios.get('api/activate?key=' + key)
    });
}
```

**check 1**

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}
```

Comment: still have same error...
I don't think it's a dispatch problem because the same method works with the other old components without dispatch

Comment: ok, I am not founding any problem with your question

Comment: please add that check 1 and try or convert that into a functional component, you can clearly see that error if it comes